# How can I change a specific part of css code in OpenCart?

Tags: html, css, opencart

This is the address of the website I'm working on : www.kristallglobal.ir 
 It's based on OpenCart and I want to change specific parts of it. The first one is the background color of this "div". I want to change it from "kinda purple" to another color. I've found its related code in the source code, but I don't know which property should I change. Here is the code.: 
`.box .box-heading {
    background-color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:600;
    line-height:22px;
    color:#000;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    padding:10px 23px 13px;
    }`


And here is the picture of it

[image: and here is the picture of the "div" I want to modify]

thanks for helping.

Comment: the element to target is header .toprow use chrome console to check for the element and then locate it on the opencart css file and replace the background color from there

Answer (score 1):

the element to target is header .toprow use chrome console to check for the element and then locate it on the opencart css file and replace the background color from there. Based on the google chrome console the style sheet to edit is named `stylesheet_rtl.css` and is located on `catalog/view/theme/theme321/stylesheet/stylesheet_rtl.css`, Goodluck :)

[image]

Comment: dear Allan thanks for your response. It was great, I did what you said; I changed the color to what I wanted. I changed the code through DirectAdmin, (I mean I found the related file, and edited its source code but it looks like the website doesn't get updated.) Should I do anything special??

Comment: There is two .box .box-heading in your css file, I suggested you've changed first one located at line 1256, though other one located at line 5456 override first one.
سلام، برای تغییر پس زمینه قسمت جدیدترین ها و برجسته ترین ها و ... مورد دوم رو تغییر بدید. در سی اس اس هر استایلی که پایین تر باشه، اولویت بیشتری داره.